Problema con graficos de Chartjs
Buen día colegas, estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación web donde se carga un archivo CSV y se muestran os datos en una tabla, pero también estoy intentando mostrar un dashboard con esos datos, el problema es que no se muestra ninguna grafica y no tengo ningun error, estoy usando la libreria Chartjs. Estees mi script de js.
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
const csvDisplay = document.getElementById("csv-display");
const alertContainer = document.getElementById("alert-container");
const dashboard = document.getElementById("dashboard");
const backButton = document.getElementById("back-button");

fileInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];

  if (!file) {
    showAlert("Por favor, seleccione un archivo CSV.", "alert-danger");
    return;
  }

  if (!file.name.endsWith(".csv")) {
    showAlert("El archivo seleccionado no es un archivo CSV.", "alert-danger");
    return;
  }

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    const csvData = event.target.result;
    displayCSV(csvData);
    generateDashboard(csvData);
  };
  reader.onerror = () => {
    showAlert("Hubo un error al leer el archivo.", "alert-danger");
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
});

function displayCSV(csvData) {
  // Limpia cualquier mensaje de alerta previo
  alertContainer.innerHTML = "";
  
  const rows = csvData.split("\n");
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("table", "table-striped");

  rows.forEach((row, index) => {
    const cols = row.split(",");
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    cols.forEach((col) => {
      const th = document.createElement(index === 0 ? "th" : "td");
      th.textContent = col.trim();
      tr.appendChild(th);
    });

    table.appendChild(tr);
  });

  csvDisplay.innerHTML = "";
  csvDisplay.appendChild(table);

  // Oculta la vista previa del CSV y muestra el dashboard
  csvDisplay.style.display = "none";
  dashboard.style.display = "block";
}

function generateDashboard(csvData) {
  // Procesar csvData para extraer información y generar gráficos
  const rows = csvData.split("\n");
  const labels = [];
  const data = [];

  rows.forEach((row, index) => {
    const cols = row.split(",");
    if (index > 0) { // Ignorar la primera fila si es el encabezado
      labels.push(cols[0]);
      data.push(parseFloat(cols[1]));
    }
  });

  console.log("Labels:", labels); // Verifica etiquetas
  console.log("Data:", data); // Verifica datos

  // Crear un gráfico usando Chart.js
  const ctx = document.createElement("canvas");
  document.getElementById("chart-container").appendChild(ctx);
  
  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Data from CSV',
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

backButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Muestra la vista previa del CSV y oculta el dashboard
  csvDisplay.style.display = "block";
  dashboard.style.display = "none";
});

Este es mi HTML, nose si el problema sea del DOM al querer renderizar los gráficos o de JavaScript. Les agradecería si me pudiesen dar una guía de que esta sucediendo, es la primera vez que uso una librería para hacer un dashboard.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>MovilT</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Gestión de Datos Móviles</h1>
        <p class="mb-4">Cargue su CSV para visualizar datos de clientes, líneas telefónicas, facturación mensual y
            servicios.</p>

        <div class="file-upload">
            <p>Suelta aquí tu archivo para empezar a subirlo</p>
            <p>O selecciona un archivo para subir</p>
            <input type="file" accept=".csv" id="fileInput">
            <button class="mt-3" id="uploadBtn">Cargar Archivo CSV</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Alert container -->
        <div id="alert-container">
        </div>

        <!-- Tabla para mostrar el contenido del CSV -->
        <div id="csv-display-print">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="csv-display"></table>
        </div>

        <!-- Dashboard container -->
        <div id="dashboard" style="display:none;">
            <button id="back-button" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
            <div id="chart-container"></div>
            <!-- Other dashboard elements -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript para manejar la carga y visualización del CSV -->
    <script src="./script.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

y este es el enlace a la web: https://pepejsc.github.io/gestionCSV/

Lo acabo de probar y anda "bien". El archivo CSV tiene esto

entonces puede ser el formato del archivo que subo?, porque tu prueba si funciona.

En efecto, es el formato de archivo. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Si ya encontraste la solución, recordá que podes crear una respuesta a tu pregunta. Si aún quisieras obtener una respuesta, por favor, presioná [edit] y agregar un ejemplo del archivo que estas utilizando.
